# phpMyAdmin's Procedure editor doesn't show parameters having underscores on the beginning

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have recently moved my stuff from Windows Server 2012 to 2016. I have installed brand new MariaDB (10.3.14) and phpMyAdmin 4.8.5.

I have some stored procedures in my database and many of them have some parameters. I always name them with an underscore on the beginning, because I don't name anything else like that. Such my own convention. But, after the migration I discovered, that all parameters have gone from the procedures code. But that happens only in phpMyAdmin. In HeidiSQL they are still present and they are working fine. On the previous machine I used the same version of phpMyAdmin and everything was fine. Now I'm scared using it on my new machine, especially editing procedures, because I'm scared that all my parameters will disappear after saving. I have to use HeidiSQL, but I don't quite like that tool and I would love to use phpMyAdmin again. Can anybody help or advise me, please?

I tried to use previous versions of phpMyAdmin, but they all give the same result. Must be the IIS or MariaDB's fault.

My parameter names example look:

_parameter1
_parameter2

Comment: If the parameters work fine in heidisql, then mariadb can hardly be at fault. IIS or the operating system may interfere, but that's ver unlikely. This is going to be a phpmyadmin thing.

Comment: The problem is that exactly the same version of phpMyAdmin on the previous machine was perfectly fine. So that's why I'm so confused...

Comment: Phpmyadmin version may be the same, but what about the configuration?

Comment: Same - the default.